# JPA @formula and Collection<?>

Tags: spring, hibernate, collections, formula

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {

    @Id 
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Address address;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)   
    @JoinColumn(name="mother", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Person mother;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="father", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Person father;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Formula(value="(SELECT DISTINCT FROM PERSON as p WHERE p.father=id OR p.mother=id)")
    private Collection<Person> children;

    //...
}
```

Greetings people of Stackoverflow!

I just started with Spring and JPA.

Basically you can see an entity called Person where I've defined following attributes like id, firstName, secondName, person's father, person's mother and person's children. Didn't add getters/setters to the post.

My first question will be, is it possible with formula to create a collection of data? Somewhere I heard it isn't possible and Internet is basically empty of data with needed specs, that's why I created this topic.

Second question, if it isn't possible then what could be the best way to describe following situation without a formula? Problem stands in linking between children with mother/father values. Basically the end result should be that JPA does the data binding.